# AC and DC Current Conduction?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

Why the current in a conductor subjected to AC voltages flows at the surface of the conductor but not at the center/core of the conductor. Please avoid mathematical relation. Just a simple theoretical explanation is required.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation you are looking for is here   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

Answer (score 0):

"Consider a multi—stranded conductor composed of ‘n’ number of strand (filaments). The AC current flowing through the inner strands produce flux which links (enclose) the inner strands only. But, the flux produced by the flow of AC current through the outer strands, links (enclose) not only the outer strands but also the inner strands. Thus,,the flux linkage per ampere to the inner strands is higher than the flux linkage per ampere to the outer strands. This causes the inductance (and hence inductive reactances) of inner strands to be much higher than for the outer strands. Thus, higher the impedance lower » is the flow of current. As a result, the outer strands carry more current than the inner strands."